# How do I get posts which have publish date greater than 6 hours with wp query wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i have tried the following code but it gives me posts within 6 hours of publish date.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'epl_registration', 
'post_status'   => 'publish',
'fields' => 'ids',
'date_query'    => array(
     'after' => '6 hours ago'
     //'after' => '6 hours' //returns empty if used
 )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I need posts that are published 6 hours ago and not published within 6 hours

Please help

Comment: I tried and your code seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with "before"?

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'epl_registration', 
'post_status'   => 'publish',
'fields' => 'ids',
'date_query'    => array(
     array(
         'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
         'before' => '6 hours ago'
     )
 )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```